# Error running python manage.py

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

I'm using `flask` with Ubuntu, and when I run `python manage.py` I get this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True,processes=True)
  File "/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 671, in run_simple
    s.bind((hostname, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default *port* for `flask` then you are using *port 5000*. Get the python open processes with:

`ps aux | grep python`

If you have more python processes open you can check what process is with the state `LISTEN` in you local address `127.0.0.1:5000` with:

`netstat -tulpn`

Kill the PID (process id) with:

`kill -9 PID`

Comment: There may be other python processes running, so this may inadvertently kill the wrong process.

Comment: I've take it in consideration. Note, by default flask port is 5000

Answer (score 6):

This means this port on the address you're trying to use (presumably `localhost`) is *already being used by another process*.

What to do to fix this:

- kill Python and restart your script
- or find a process that's using your port and kill it
- use another port for your app
- wait for a few minutes, perhaps this port hasn't been 'freed' yet

Answer (score 0):

This means another process has got the port you want to use open for listening, most likely because a previous invocation of your server crashed, or was quit, and didn't clean up. You can see what process has the port in question open (by default 5000 for Flask servers) with

```
$ PIDTOKILL=`sudo netstat -tnp | grep ":5000" | awk '{ print $7 }' | cut -d '/' -f 1`
$ kill $PIDTOKILL
```

If that still doesn't work, use

```
$ kill -9 $PIDTOKILL
```

The other possible problem is that you are genuinely trying to run flask using a port that is already claimed by another service entirely, in which case just change your port.